# Javascript Slider doesn't work correctly with transition end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know why people's are not answering this question.I'm making a horizontal infinite loop slider. What approach i'm using is making a `ul` container which has 3 images, for example if there are 3 images then clone the first image and place it to the end of the slider, same with last image make clone and place it before the first image. So now total images are 5. Default slider translation always start from first image not from clone one. Here is an [example](http://output.jsbin.com/ufoceq/8/). What i'm facing is, I want to reset the slider after slider comes to the last clone image with same continuous loop like a carousel slider. I try using addEventListener with the event name transitionend but that event doesn't perform correctly and showing unsatisfied behavior. Is there a way to fix this?

```js
(function () {
    var resetTranslation = "translate3d(-300px,0px,0px)";
    var elm = document.querySelector('.Working');
    elm.style.transform = resetTranslation;
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.Working li');
    var clonefirst,
        clonelast,
        width = 300;
    index = 2;
    clonefirst = arr[0].cloneNode(true);
    clonelast = arr[arr.length - 1].cloneNode(true);

    elm.insertBefore(clonelast, arr[0]);
    arr[arr.length - 1].parentNode.insertBefore(clonefirst, arr[arr.length - 1].nextSibling);
    //Update
    arr = document.querySelectorAll('.Working li');
    elm.style.transition = 'transform 1.5s ease';

    setInterval(function () {

        elm.style.transform = 'translate3d(-' + index * width + 'px,0px,0px)';
        if (index == arr.length - 1) {
            elm.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
                elm.style.transform = resetTranslation;
            });
            index = 1;
        }
        index++;

    }, 4000)

})();
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 320px;
    width: 300px;


}

.Working{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 3125%;


}
.Working li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}


img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.SubContainer:after{
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="SubContainer Working">
        <li> <img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/HqQb9V9.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/PMBBc07.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img  class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/GRrGSxe.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not to sidetrack your question but you may want to try something more device friendly. Check out my codepen for a slider in js.  http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/NbpPvL

Comment: It is obvious, When you translate all of the images, There is no process to change them back to their original position. Your translation resumes, but the images are going toward the `- infinite`

Comment: I recently coded an infinite carousel which also transitions the container. When the container reaches the last item - I reset the transition. It also uses the flexbox `order` property to rearrange the items back (no cloning is necessary). Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/mOojWV) (Uncomment `overflow: hidden` on the wpr to see the result) If this is what you're looking for, I could post this as an answer :)

Comment: @hamel123 why you are not using Danield  Codepen , which is i n the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transition end` event is not immediately fire because last transition doesn't computed when last clone image appear. You can easily achieve this thing by using `setTimeout` function and pass number of milliseconds to wait, after that reset the translation. I don't know it's an efficient solution but i think its easily done by using this function.
Now I'm fixing your code with this.

```js
(function () {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.Working');
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.Working li');
    var clonefirst,
        clonelast,
        width = 300;
    index = 2;
    clonefirst = arr[0].cloneNode(true);
    clonelast = arr[arr.length - 1].cloneNode(true);

    elm.insertBefore(clonelast, arr[0]);
    arr[arr.length - 1].parentNode.insertBefore(clonefirst, arr[arr.length - 1].nextSibling);
    //Update
    arr = document.querySelectorAll('.Working li');

     setInterval(function () {
        $(elm).css({
            'transform': 'translate3d(-' + (index * width) + 'px,0px,0px)',
            'transition': 'transform 1.5s ease'
        });
        if (index == arr.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(elm).css({'transform': 'translate3d(-300px,0px,0px)', 'transition': 'none'});
                index = 1;
            }, 1400);

        }
        index++;

    }, 2000)

})();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 320px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 8px;

}

.Working {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-300px);
    width: 3125%;

}

.Working li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.SubContainer:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

#checkboxer:checked + .wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkboxer">Remove Overflow Hidden</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxer" name="checkboxer"/>

<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="SubContainer Working">
        <li> <img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/HqQb9V9.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/PMBBc07.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img  class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/GRrGSxe.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've messed around with your code to hack in a fix: https://jsfiddle.net/rap8o3q0/

The changed part:

```
var currentItem = 1;

setInterval(function () {
    var getWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if(len === currentItem){
        i = 1;
        currentItem = 1;
    } else {
        currentItem++;
        i++;
    }

    var val = 'translate3d(-' + (i-1) * getWidth + 'px,0px,0px)';
    UnorderedListElement.style.transform = val;

}, 3000);
```

Comment: Is there a way to continuously start slide from left.

Comment: So there's no animation back to the start point? Yeah, there is, and it would require having "clone" elements at the start and end of the slider - this would make the code a lot more advanced :)

Comment: what do you mean by clone elements.

Comment: I'm cloning first & last image but now what i'm doing wrong. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/johncris/pen/bqjBgo)

Answer (score 0):

To come back your slider in its first position, you need to trigger a `transition end` event after the last (3th) translation, That works only one time.

```
$(UnorderedListElement).one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function ()
    {
        {
            $(UnorderedListElement).css('transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)');

        }
    });
```

But you need to make it to translate immediately. In link below you can see my slider that is very similar to yours, but works by absolute positioning and change the `left` property instead of transform.

[Slider](http://daryayenoorclinic.com/)

**Last thing**: It is not a good idea to slide the hole of the image container. You must slide your images separately. In your way there is an obvious problem: When the page is sliding out the last image, there is not the next image to push it!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `setInterval` as

```
  setInterval(function() {
    var getWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var val = 'translate3d(-' + i * getWidth + 'px,0px,0px)';
    UnorderedListElement.style.transform = val;

    i++;
    if (i == 3) { //assuming three images here 
      i = 0
    }


  }, 3000)
```

```js
var DomChanger;

(function() {


  var listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.ah-slider li');
  var len = listItem.length;


  var getImage = document.querySelector('.ah-slider li img');
  var UnorderedListElement = document.querySelector('.ah-slider');


  var outerDiv = document.querySelector('.Slider');

  UnorderedListElement.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + (len * 1000 + 215) + '%');


  var i = 1;

  DomChanger = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      listItem[i].setAttribute('style', 'width:' + window.innerWidth + 'px');
    }
    outerDiv.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + getImage.clientHeight + 'px');

  };


  setInterval(function() {
    var getWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var val = 'translate3d(-' + i * getWidth + 'px,0px,0px)';
    UnorderedListElement.style.transform = val;

    i++;
    if (i == 3) {
      i = 0
    }


  }, 3000)


})();





window.onload = function() {
  DomChanger();

};
window.onresize = function() {

  DomChanger();
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.Slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ah-slider {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.ah-slider li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.ah-slider li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.clearFix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="Slider">
  <ul class="ah-slider clearFix">
    <li>
      <a href=""><img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/L9Zi1UR.jpg" title="" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img class="" src="http://i.imgur.com/FEcEwFs.jpg" title="" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><img  class="" src=http://i.imgur.com/hURSKNa.jpg" title="" /></a></li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i re-edit my question now you can see this what is happening?

Comment: but why slider goes back to first image i want to start it again as a continuous loop